# Error with the correlative number figure/table for all document

Tags: tables, floats

[image]

Hello friends, I'm trying create a correlative number in all the document, but when it begins in new chapter it begins since number one again. Thank for all!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Since different document classes set up the numbering in different ways, we absolutely must know what document class you are using.  For the quickest and most accurate responses, without guessing, please provide a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem, begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, that a helper can copy-and-paste to experiment.

Comment: I write the source code in this link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15Uui-1ChL-Zsjxz-BJ1nGD1_bGBYY7ySoyoGlcQnR6Y/edit?usp=sharing

I'm sorry, it is a little long. This generate, before code

\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{30pt}% More space
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{tabprefix}{#1\tablename~#2.}
\captionsetup[table]{listformat=tabprefix}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{30pt}% More space
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figprefix}{#1\figurename~#2.}
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figprefix}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

Thanks!!

Comment: \usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

it was the answer!!! thanks for all!

Comment: @Guillermo `\usepackage{chngcntr}` is no longer needed.